# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fdef86e27d8>

Tags: python, generator

I have the following code python 3 which wants to print the output to the file homology.txt, but I am getting the following typical output for all the lines in the output file homology.txt

```
<0> 0:<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fdef86e27d8>.
```

The code is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dionysus as d
import numpy as np

points =np.loadtxt('./1A1P.pts')
print("Number of Points:", len(points))
f = d.fill_rips(points, 3, 6)
#print(f)
p = d.homology_persistence(f, prime = 2)
for i, c in enumerate(p):
#print(i,c)
print(f[i], end=':',file = open('homology.txt', 'a'))
print(list([(x.element, f[x.index])] for x in c), file = open('homology.txt', 'a'))
```

Comment: It seems that you want to call `list` or so on the generator rather than printing it, but I don’t see how this code can generate that output.  Double check it’s what you’re running?

Comment: For future reference: calling `open` repeatedly like that is slow and may not work on all Python versions.  Use `with open('homology.txt', 'a') as f:`.

Comment: I ended up commenting out the second print statement and chaning the first pritn statement to print(str(f[i]) +':'+ str([(x.element, f[x.index]) for x in c])  ,file = open('homology1.txt', 'a')) and it worked. It did not give me the generator output. It gave me the output I expected. Am not sure why but it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will keep that in mind! Sincerely Jon

Comment: Also, a single `open` can often use `'w'`, which avoids accidentally accumulating data from multiple runs.